# What is the correct way to create a resource in a Puppet provider?

Tags: puppet

I'm currently writing a provider that acts as a "resource wrapper". Essentially, it takes a name, type, some parameters, and then creates a resource based on that.

I've been using `Puppet::Resource.new(<type>, <name>, parameters: <parameters>)`, but it doesn't seem to take into account `Sensitive` parameters.

For example, I try to create a `File` resource, like so:

```
Puppet::Resource.new('file', '/root/.ssh/id_rsa', parameters: params)
```

If the params contain a `Sensitive` value, it gives me the following error:

```
Could not evaluate: Parameter content failed on File[/root/.ssh/id_ra]: 
Munging failed for value #<Sensitive [value redacted]> in class 
content: no implicit conversion of 
Puppet::Pops::Types::PSensitiveType::Sensitive into String
```

What resource creation call do I need to make for all parameters (sensitive or not) to be handled correctly?

EDIT: I need a custom type and provider because of what I'm trying to accomplish. I want to manage resources that need to reliably know a user's home directory. For example, I want to manage `/home/<user>/.vimrc` without knowing what that directory is beforehand. The new resource type is meant to "wrap" resources with the user's home directory. Writing a custom type and provider is the only way I know to do this.

EDIT 2: I've tried the following, as suggested, to mark the parameter as sensitive:

```
params = {
  name: '/root/.ssh/id_rsa',
  owner: 'root',
  <more parameters...>
  sensitive_parameters: ['content'],
}
Puppet::Type.type('file').new params
```

This doesn't seem to have any effect (I'm still getting the same error), even though it looks like it should (according to the source code for puppet/type.rb).

Comment: You can already do this with Puppet DSL: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/lang_resources_advanced.html#using-an-abstract-resource-type (and related articles plus clever coding). This is not really a good path for a provider. At the very least, this would be done with a type instead.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having to explain why I'm using a provider, but please see the updated question.

Comment: Ok, but my point still stands that the problem and solution here lie more with the type than the provider. The munging occurs in the type, so you can avoid the conversion with your own proper munge there.

Comment: Doesn't the error indicate that it's the File type (not my defined type) that's having trouble with Munging?

Comment: This is really a custom type and not a defined type, but yes it is the `file` type having issues with the `Sensitive` data type you are passing in. You need to handle the conversion our let Puppet handle the conversion by appropriately marking the parameter as sensitive. You can see the helper method that `file` invokes here: https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/master/lib/puppet/type/file.rb#L896-L929. I would expect marking your parameter as sensitive so that helper method does the work for you to be the easiest path forward here. This is just a broad suggestion though.

Comment: Gave that shot--getting the same error. See my updated question for the call I used.